# Can we make Print button without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, accessibility

Can we make Print button without JavaScript? to open browser print window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML has no built-in "print" action for an anchor tag or input button (or anything else), so JavaScript is your way. You could also include instructions for your users on how to print using File->Print or the other various alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Althought as @Pablo says there is no print functionality that can be used without javascript, here is something that will make it a little nicer just in case there was a user that had javascript disabled:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/how_to_create_an_unobtrusive_print_this_page_link_with_javascript/

Comment: StackOverflow just does *not* like your link text. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a Java applet but javascript is simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Not with straight HTML.  You could do it with Java, ActiveX, etc, but those are even more to add than JavaScript.