# HTML - Link that automatically prints page

Tags: html, printing

**What I have to do:**

Create a link (HTML `<a>` tag) that automatically prints the page (like if the user would have pressed CTRL + P)

Could not find a clear answer around the web. Some tend to Javascript, but is there a way to do it without using JS? (If my website falls in the hands of an old lady that for some reason doesn't have JS activated... you never know.)

Comment: Possible dulpicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720013/can-we-make-print-button-without-javascript

Comment: Ok thanks. Admins should close this one then (I don't have enough rep.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - JavaScript is the only way to do this.  You could generate a print-only version (server-side), and end up with a link such as `<a href='page.php?print=1'>print version</a>` and have clear instructions on how to print it on this page.

(Incidentally, an old lady is probably more likely to have JS enabled, in my experience it's people who are more au fait with the web technologies who tend to have things like JS disabled for various reasons).

Comment: Thats great thanks! And with your comment, I think it would be safe to use JS anyway.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is the only way, you can do this though with the function `print()` it is simple and doesn’t require any JS knowledge. What you can do is add a `<button>` and inside that button all you have to do is `onclick=“print()”`. Finished code:

```html
<a onclick="print()">Print This Page</a>

<p>this text along with the button will be printed</p>
```

Comment: I did a little change. It used to be a button, now it is an `<a>` link