# Link to print a URL

Tags: javascript, html, http, printing, http-headers

I want to have a page open but instead of viewing it, it asks the user to print.

This is incredibly similar to the functionality of the [`Content Disposition`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml) HTTP header. 
When set to `attachment` it will ask the user where to save the file (instead of displaying it in browser).

I have the privilege of opening the page for the user so I could [use javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.print?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.print):

```js
var doc = open(url); //open the link for them instead of using an anchor href
doc.print(); //ask them to print it, this is a blocking call until the user is done
doc.close(); //immediately close the window so the user isn't interrupted
```

But I was really hoping there was some server-side flag I could utilise, is there such a thing?

<sub>The page being opened isn't necessarily a HTML document, so using `window.print();window.close();` inside it wouldn't work in all cases.</sub>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we make Print button without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720013/can-we-make-print-button-without-javascript)

Comment: HTTP isn't HTML, but it does seem like your answer shows that HTTP has no goodies either

Comment: also, that question, I think, is referring to printing the page it is currently on. Not linking to a document *in which* a print dialogue is to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You've confused what server-side and client-side languages do.

A server-side language, such as PHP or ASP performs things on the server, like calculating prices on a web shop.

The `Content-Disposition: attachment` header is a bit of an oddity in this respect, since it controls the *client* rather than the server.

A client-side language - in this case JavaScript - performs what happens on the user's browser.

Printing is a client-side feature. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: exactly. I'm fishing for more of these oddities, if they exist

Comment: @Hashbrown There isn't anything to print.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to post an answer in Javascript because it's actually not trivial :(
What I wrote in the question won't work cross browser (it's actually Firefox, not IE this time!)

The problem was that, in Firefox, [`print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.print?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.print) is actually non-blocking, so in my above example, the newly `open()`'d window would close before Firefox printed it!

So, you can either leave the window open, or you can try using a hidden frame;

```
function printUrl(url) {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame.setAttribute('src', url);

    //must be in the DOM to work in Firefox/IE
    document.body.appendChild(frame);

    //since it's in the DOM we need to hide it (lest we ruin our page layout)
    //can't use 'display:none' or 'visibility:hidden' because you can't get focus (needed for IE)
    //'z-index:-1' & 'opacity:0' wont help if there is no background in the elements above it and someone clicks through to it
    frame.style.position = 'absolute';
    frame.style.left = '-9999px';

    //when it is loaded, print it
    function printFrame() {
        //have to get focus in IE
        frame.contentWindow.focus();

        //print!
        frame.contentWindow.print();

        /* cant remove the element because print() is non-blocking in FF
         * (I.e. it would remove the frame before it was printed!)
        //cleanup
        //document.body.removeChild(frame);*/
    };

    //if it was cached, it may already be done (onload wont fire, IE8)
    if (frame.contentWindow && frame.contentDocument.readyState == 'complete')
        printFrame();
    else {
        if (frame.addEventListener)
            //W3C
            frame.addEventListener('load', printFrame, false);
        else
            //IE<9
            frame.attachEvent('onload', printFrame);
    }
}
```

Tested to work in FF, Chrome and IE>7
Note that, like with the simple `open()` (if it worked), this won't work cross-site. You can't access `window` methods of pages on a different domain, either in a popup or a frame.